# Dynamic Dependent Menu - Values are not changing

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to setup a dynamic dependent menu with ajax. The Select options are populated through the database. There are three tables associated with this 
1. customers
2. companies
3. company_customer

customers and companies has a many to many relationship

When a customer is selected, the relevant company/companies should appear

I am using Laravel 5.5

**routes**

```
Route::get('', 'CustomerController@list');
Route::post('fetch','CustomerController@fetch')->name('dynamicdependent.fetch');
```

**CustomerController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Customer;
use App\Company;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{

    public function list()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        $companies = Company::all();

        return view('list', compact('customers', 'companies'));
    }


    public function fetch(Request $request)
    {

        $select = $request->get('select');
        $value = $request->get('value');
        $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
        $data = DB::table('company_customer')
        ->where($select, $value)
        ->groupBy($dependent)
        ->get();
        $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
        }
        echo $output;
        return view('fetch');
    }

}
```

**list.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {{-- Jquery Data Table css--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    {{-- Jquery --}}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    {{-- Jquery Data Table js--}}
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="customer">Customer</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" data-dependent="company">
                    @foreach ($customers as $customer)
                        <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{ $customer->customer }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="company">Company</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="company" id="company">
                    @foreach ($companies as $company)
                        <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{ $company->company }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

  </body>


  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){



         $('.dynamic').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() != '')
          {
           var select = $(this).attr("id");
           var value = $(this).val();
           var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
           var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
           $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('dynamicdependent.fetch') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
            success:function(result)
            {
             $('#'+dependent).html(result);
            }

           })
          }
         });

         $('#customer').change(function(){
          $('#company').val('');          
         });


        });
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, your route to fetch records is

`Route::get('fetch','CustomerController@fetch')->name('dynamicdependent.fetch');`

Where as in your `list.blade.php` script to fetch records you are calling that route with

`method:"POST"`

make sure you either change the route to `post` in your routes file or change it to `get` in your script. Let us know if this solved it.

Comment: Route::post('fetch','CustomerController@fetch')->name('dynamicdependent.fetch'); Still the same result though

Comment: `var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();`
This input is also missing from your code. This is csrf token which is required for post requests.

Comment: I was referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7-HkztGahM tutorial. Actually my ajax knowledge is really bad and my jquery knowledge is also not that good. Trying to figure this out.